# How to write data to a range of cells in Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thank you for taking the time to read my question. This is my first attempt at writing some code in Google Sheets. I have a lot of experience in Excel VBA. I am not a programmer.

I have watched a lot of videos and have been able to create an HTML form on which I can click a button and populate my form with data from the worksheet based on the row number of the active cell.

I'm now trying to figure out how I write the data back to the same row that I took it from after editing values in the form.

I am able to write it to a new row, just not back to the same row I got the data from.

I created a var at the top of my Code.gs file called: IsTaskEdit

var IsTaskEdit = 0;

I have an HTML form, and this is the relevant code that gets data from my worksheet

```
function getExistingTask(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(aftergetExistingTask).getTaskData();
      }

      function aftergetExistingTask(values){
        document.getElementById("idWBS").value = values[0][1];
        document.getElementById("idTaskName").value = values[0][2];
        document.getElementById("idResourceName").value = values[0][3];
        document.getElementById("idPercDone").value = values[0][8];
        document.getElementById("idNotes").value = values[0][0];
        document.getElementById("idPreds").value = values[0][7];
      }
```

This is the actual code that gets the data from my worksheet and is called from an HTML form. I set IsTaskEdit to the row number of the active cell and I want to use it later to know what row to write to

```
//Get the data of for the active row based on activecell
function getTaskData(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("ProjectPlan");
  var ac = ss.getActiveCell();
  var ar = ac.getRow();
  var values = ws.getRange(ar,NOTESCOL,1,PERCDONECOL-NOTESCOL+1).getValues();
  IsTaskEdit = ar;
  return values;
}

//Make TAKSID value
function makeTaskIDNew(strTask){
  var arrTask = strTask.split(".");
  var tTaskID = "";
  arrTask.forEach(
    function(value){
      tTaskID = tTaskID + (value + "000").slice(0,3);
    }
  )
  return tTaskID
}
```

This is the code that runs when I click the Submit button on my HTML form. I'm hoping that I can use IsTaskEdit as a signal to know if the user is adding a new row or editing an existing one. If it's a new one, IsTaskEdit === 0 then write to a new row, otherwise try and write to the row specified by IsTaskEdit value.

```
function afterButtonClicked(){
    var vWBS =  document.getElementById("idWBS");
    var vTaskName =  document.getElementById("idTaskName");
    var vResourceName =  document.getElementById("idResourceName");
    var vStartDate =  document.getElementById("idStartDate");
    var vFinishDate =  document.getElementById("idFinishDate");
    var vPercDone =  document.getElementById("idPercDone");
    var vNotes =  document.getElementById("idNotes");

    var TaskData = {WBS:vWBS.value ,TaskName:vTaskName.value ,ResourceName:vResourceName.value ,StartDate:vStartDate.value ,FinishDate:vFinishDate.value ,PercDone:vPercDone.value ,Notes:vNotes.value};
    google.script.run.addNewRow(TaskData);
    google.script.host.close();
  }
```

```
//Add new row when the UserForm button is clicked
function addNewRow(rowData){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("ProjectPlan");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow()+1
  ws.getRange(IsTaskEdit,TASKIDCOL,1,PERCDONECOL-TASKIDCOL+1).setValues([TaskIDFormula.replace(/~/g,WBSCOLlet+lr),rowData.Notes,rowData.WBS,rowData.TaskName,rowData.ResourceName,rowData.StartDate,rowData.FinishDate,"DateDiff",rowData.PercDone]);
    

  if(IsTaskEdit === 0){
    ws.appendRow([TaskIDFormula.replace(/~/g,WBSCOLlet+lr),rowData.Notes,rowData.WBS,rowData.TaskName,rowData.ResourceName,rowData.StartDate,rowData.FinishDate,"DateDiff",rowData.PercDone]);
  }
  else {
    ws.getRange(IsTaskEdit,TASKIDCOL,1,PERCDONECOL-TASKIDCOL+1).setValues([TaskIDFormula.replace(/~/g,IsTaskEdit+lr),rowData.Notes,rowData.WBS,rowData.TaskName,rowData.ResourceName,rowData.StartDate,rowData.FinishDate,"DateDiff",rowData.PercDone]);
    IsTaskEdit = 0;
  }
}
```

addNewRow worked before I added the If(IsTaskEdit === 0) part and I only had the we.appendRow(... part.

I'm not sure how I write to a row based on IsTaskEdit.

Any and all help is greatly apprecaited.

thanks

I've watched many YouTube videos and read many stackoverflow threads but have not been able to piece this together.

Comment: Can you please provide your html code so we can replicate your concern? Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please take this opportunity to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: It would be helpful to understand the nature of your scenario. Anyway, the attributes for `ws.getRange()` are `row, column, numRows, numColumns` where row and column are index values starting with 1. `IsTaskEdit`, the "row" value for "ws.getRange()", **cannot** have a value of 0. Would you please explain your understanding of EXACTLY how you know whether the user is adding a new row or editing an existing one.

Comment: Related (homework?) question: [Google Apps Script will not pass data with dates to HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75700417/1330560)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all that replied. I managed to figure out that I cannot save a variable and keep it over time... so what I did was pass my row number to my HTML form and then use it when writing back to Google Sheets.

IsTaskEdit does not um... stay existing, therefore I can't use it as a condition. That is why I passed a value to the form and hid it, then use it when sending data back.

This is where I store the Google Sheets Row Number:
var vTaskRow = document.getElementById("idFromRow");

```js
//Send Task Data from form to Project Sheet
      function afterButtonClicked(){
        var vWBS =  document.getElementById("idWBS");
        var vTaskName =  document.getElementById("idTaskName");
        //var vResourceName =  document.getElementById("idResourceName");
        var vStartDate =  document.getElementById("idStartDate");
        var vFinishDate =  document.getElementById("idFinishDate");
        var vPercDone =  document.getElementById("idPercDone");
        var vPreds =  document.getElementById("idPreds");
        var vNotes =  document.getElementById("idNotes");
        var vTaskRow = document.getElementById("idFromRow");

        var TaskData = {WBS:vWBS.value ,TaskName:vTaskName.value  ,ResourceName:getSelectedOptions() ,StartDate:vStartDate.value ,FinishDate:vFinishDate.value ,PercDone:vPercDone.value ,Notes:vNotes.value, Preds:vPreds.value, TaskRow:vTaskRow.value};

        google.script.run.addNewRow(TaskData);
        //google.script.host.close();
      }
```

Then in my Google Sheets code file I am able to use the value passed back to determine if I need to write a new row or update one

```js
//Add new row when the UserForm button is clicked
function addNewRow(rowData){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("ProjectPlan");
  var lr = ws.getLastRow()+1;
  var strSelectedResources = rowData.ResourceName.join();
  strSelectedResources = strSelectedResources.replaceAll(",",", ");
  
  if((rowData.TaskRow*1) === 0){
  //and so on
```

Thanks again.